# TensorFlow restore throwing "No Variable to save" error

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am working through some code to understand how to save and restore checkpoints in tensorflow. To do so, I implemented a simple neural netowork that works with MNIST digits and saved the .ckpt file like so:

```
    from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import numpy as np

learning_rate = 0.001
n_input = 784 # MNIST data input (img shape = 28*28)
n_classes = 10 # MNIST total classes 0-9

#import MNIST data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('.', one_hot = True)

#Features and Labels 
features = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_input])
labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_classes])

#Weights and biases
weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_classes]))
bias = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))

#logits = xW + b
logits = tf.add(tf.matmul(features, weights), bias)

#Define loss and optimizer
cost = tf.reduce_mean(\
  tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=labels))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)\
.minimize(cost)


# Calculate accuracy
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits, 1), tf.argmax(labels, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))


import math

save_file = './train_model.ckpt'
batch_size = 128
n_epochs = 100

saver = tf.train.Saver()

# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    # Training cycle
    for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        total_batch = math.ceil(mnist.train.num_examples / batch_size)

        # Loop over all batches
        for i in range(total_batch):
            batch_features, batch_labels = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
            sess.run(
                optimizer,
                feed_dict={features: batch_features, labels: batch_labels})

        # Print status for every 10 epochs
        if epoch % 10 == 0:
            valid_accuracy = sess.run(
                accuracy,
                feed_dict={
                    features: mnist.validation.images,
                    labels: mnist.validation.labels})
            print('Epoch {:<3} - Validation Accuracy: {}'.format(
                epoch,
                valid_accuracy))

    # Save the model
    saver.save(sess, save_file)
    print('Trained Model Saved.')
```

This part works well, and I get the .ckpt file saved in the correct directory. The problem comes in when I try to restore the model in an attempt to work on it again. I use the following code to restore the model:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:
  saver.restore(sess, 'train_model.ckpt.meta')
  print('model restored')
```

and end up with the error: `ValueError: No variables to save`

Not too sure, what the mistake here is. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

A `Graph` is different to the `Session`. A graph is the set of operations joining tensors, each of which is a symbolic representation of a set of values. A `Session` assigns specific values to the `Variable` tensors, and allows you to `run` operations in that graph.

The chkpt file saves variable values - i.e. those saved in the weights and biases - but not the graph itself.

The solution is simple: re-run the graph construction (everything before the `Session`, then start your session and load values from the chkpt file.

Alternatively, you can check out [this guide for exporting and importing `MetaGraph`s](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/meta_graph).

Answer (score 1):

You should tell the `Saver` which `Variables` to restore, default Saver will get all the `Variables` from the default graph.

As in your case, you should add the constructing graph code before  `saver = tf.train.Saver()`